# UIScrollView SubViews won't resize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

**Design:**
View Hierarchy is as below:

- `UIScrollView` (for paging multiple image)

  - `UIScrollView` (for enabling zoom on the `UIImageView`)

    - `UIImageView`

      - `UIView` (origin,size relative to `UIImage` in `UIImageView`)
      - `UIView`
      - `UIView` ...
  - `UIScrollview`

    - `UIImageView`

      - `UIView`
      - `UIView` ...
  - `UIScrollView` ... and so on

**Implementation:**

```
- (id)init  
{  
self = [super init];  
if (self) {  
    // Custom initialization  
    self.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;  
    self.maximumZoomScale = 4.0f;  
    self.zoomScale = 1.0f;  
    self.bouncesZoom = true;  
    self.bounces = true;  
    self.tag = 10;  
    self.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false;  
    self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;  

    self.zoomView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.zoomView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.zoomView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
}

return self;
}  
- (void)displayImage:(UIImage *)image  
{    
// Set the image in the view  
[_zoomView setImage:image];  

// Set the Frame size to the size of image size  
// Ex. Resulting ScrollView frame = {0,0},{1250,1500}  
// Ex. Resulting ImageView frame = {0,0}, {1250,1500}  
CGRect scrollFrame = self.frame;  
scrollFrame.size.width = image.size.width;  
scrollFrame.size.height = image.size.height;  
self.frame = scrollFrame;  

CGRect iViewFrame = _zoomView.frame;  
iViewFrame.size.width = image.size.width;  
iViewFrame.size.height = image.size.height;  
_zoomView.frame = iViewFrame;  

// Add subviews before resetting the contentsize  
for (customClass* field in list.fields) {  

    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([field.x floatValue], [field.y floatValue], [field.width floatValue], [field.height floatValue])];  
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];  
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;  

    [_zoomView addSubview:view];  
}  

// Set the Frame size to the size of scrollview frame size  
// Ex. Resulting ScrollView Frame = {0,0},{320,460}  
// Ex. Resulting ImageView Frame = {0,0},{320,460}  
CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.frame;  
scrollViewFrame.size.width = 320.0f;  
scrollViewFrame.size.height = 460.0f;  
self.frame = scrollViewFrame;  

CGRect imageViewFrame = _zoomView.frame;  
imageViewFrame.size.width = self.bounds.size.width;  
imageViewFrame.size.height = self.bounds.size.height;  
_zoomView.frame = imageViewFrame;  


self.contentSize = _zoomView.bounds.size;  

[self addSubview:_zoomView];  
}
```

Above is the code that I tried implementing. It adds the `UIView`s to the `UIImageView` inside the `UIScrollView`. But the relative origin of the `UIView` is not correct (both before and after resizing).

Is there anything I should be doing differently to get the `UIView`s correctly placed inside the `UIImageView`?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What are you wanting the subviews of the image view to show?  Is there something you have done that is not working, or are you just asking if this will work?

Comment: Simon, i have edited the question. I have also added the code snippet that i tried implementing. Hope this helps make it a bit more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was top hit on Google for "scrollview subviews wont resize". For anyone else following that link:

Looking at your source, and comparing to mine, I realised that in Interface Builder, my NIB file had the tickbox for "auto size subviews" unticked. I have a vague memory this might be because in an old version of Xcode (this is an old project that's been maintained for a while) ... UIScrollView defaulted to having it switched off.

So: check that you've got it set correctly in Xcode / Interface Builder, and/or that you're setting it in code.